# base64 encode is giving me strange results after using url rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, base64

I have a really strange problem

ok the problem is thus

let say I have this url

http://www.example.com/?file=WFS010C.part3.rar&url=http://www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar

If I do `base64_encode($_GET['url'])`

the results is this

`aHR0cDovL3d3dy5maWxlc2VydmUuY29tL2ZpbGUvdkVwQnlwMy9XRlMwMTBDLnBhcnQzLnJhcg`==

after applying this rewrite condition

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^file-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ index.php?file=$1&url=$2
```

The url is like this

http://www.example.com/file-WFS010C.part3.rar-http://www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar.html

now if I do `base64_encode($_GET['url'])`

the results is this

```
aHR0cDovd3d3LmZpbGVzZXJ2ZS5jb20vZmlsZS92RXBCeXAzL1dGUzAxMEMucGFydDMucmFy
```

**Note that the value of $_GET['url'] is exactly the same in both cases if printed without encoding!!!!

how come same string giving different results just after using rewrite ?**

Does anyone know whats the problem

Comment: The second string decodes to `http:/www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar` with only one `/` after `http:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base64_decode` to see whether they are same.

In fact:

The first one is
**http://www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar**

And the second one is 
**http:/www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar**

You can see, they are not same.

Answer (score 1):

You are rewriting your URl so the part after the second `-` is stored in `url`  parameter. So in second case you receive `url` = `http://www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar.html`. Just like you had before.

What you are encoding is marked with bold:

With first url

http://www.example.com/?file=WFS010C.part3.rar&url=**http://www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar**

With second URL you are rewriting it to

http://www.example.com/index.php?file=WFS010C.part3.rar&url=**http://www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar**

**UPDATE** your second base64_encoded URL is decoding to `http:/www.fileserve.com/file/vEpByp3/WFS010C.part3.rar`. Note single `/` after http. Are you sure you have no typos in second URL?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to urlencode the 'url' parameter. I'm guessing the parameter does not get correctly parsed because of invalid characters like '/' in it.